# How to disable link but keep data-toggle drop down working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dotnetnuke

I am working on a menu, using bootstrap.

The menu has 3 levels.
Main > first submenu > second submenu

[image]

The menu items in the first submenu which has the second submenu needs to be clickable also. That's already working. The submenus are shown on desktop by hovering but on mobile you need to click on the menu item to open the submenu. So on mobile, I want this href to be gone.

[image]

At the moment I am using this code to remove it on mobile:

```
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
        $(".dropdown-toggle").each(function(){
            $(".dropdown-toggle").removeAttr("data-target");
            $(".dropdown-toggle").removeAttr("href");
        })  
    } 

    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            $(".dropdown-toggle").each(function(){
                $(".dropdown-toggle").removeAttr("href");
            })  
        }
    });
});
```

But the problem with this code is that it is still gone when you go back to a resolution which is more then 768. That happens when you go in landscape mode on a tablet.

I have already been searching for this. I found that you could add the class 'disabled' or that you could style it with pointer-events:none. But all those solutions also disables the data-toggle="dropdown" function...

So how am I able to disable the href but keep the data-toggle working?

Thanks in advance!

this is the html I use just in case:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default lumenisInnerMenu" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse lumenisListItems">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                [*>NODE]
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

[>NODE]
    <li class="[?SELECTED]dir current[/?][?NODE] dropdown-submenu HasChildren child[=DEPTH] dropdownmenu [/?]">
    [?ENABLED]
        <a href="[=URL]" class="[?NODE] dropdown-toggle[/?]" [?NODE] data-target="[=URL]" data-toggle="dropdown" [/?]>
                <div class="textsubitem">
                    <span>[=TEXT]</span>
                </div>
        </a>
    [?ELSE]
        <a href="#" [?NODE] [/?]> [?NODE]
            <span>[=TEXT]</span>[/?]
        </a>
    [/?]
    [?NODE]
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown[=DEPTH]" id="[=ID]">
            [*>NODE]
        </ul>
    [/?]
    </li>
[/>]
```

Comment: You cannot pass your window resize code or your mobile detection code in your javascript because of the first if condition `if ($(window).width() > 768) {}`. How should this work?

Answer (score 0):

just use this.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" >Anything goes here</a>
```

do not use

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").removeAttr("href");
```

with this

Comment: @JanatbekSharsheyev the question is The menu items in the first submenu which has the second submenu needs to be clickable also. That's already working. The submenus are shown on desktop by hovering but on mobile you need to click on the menu item to open the submenu. So on mobile, I want this href to be gone. 
So if you use  
  href="javascript:void(0)"  
then even in mobile view touching that particular where href is this , you will not be navigated to any page.

Comment: @JanatbekSharsheyev I think you are trying to comment on the question. But you are commenting on my answer.

Comment: and why not use href="javascript:void(0)" for this.